# Keeping images within borders

Tags: image, border

I'm pretty new to coding and I'm trying to keep these images within the borders.
Here's a jfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/9vz8o6Lj/

```
<div class="div5">
```

## Hungrybox

Juan "Hungrybox" Debiedma (June 21, 1993)

Considered to be the best Jigglypuff player in the world across all games

Ranked 5th in Melee from 2013-2015

I imagine a lot of the code is rough but any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following style to the CSS class of the divs that need to enclose floated images:

```
overflow: auto;
```

By the way, you don't need a separate CSS class for each div. Each of your .div1 through .div5 classes have the same styling. Just use one class for each div.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks a bunch. And thanks for the advice!

Comment: @PatrickJudePike Great to hear! If you wouldn't mind, I'd appreciate it if you accepted my answer as the solution by clicking the checkmark next to the up/down arrows beside my answer as well as clicking the up arrow next to my answer. Thanks!